# Form data default value not getting assigned in REST API

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am working on an API built using REST (using jersey framework).

I have created an input form schema as:

```
<xs:complexType name="InputForm">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="A" type="xs:boolean" />
        <xs:element name="B" type="xs:string" default="xyz" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:completeType>
```

The generated java file is:

```
public class InputForm{
    @XmlElement(defaultValue = "true")
    protected boolean A;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "xyz")
    protected String B;
}
```

with their respective set and get methods.

now i am sending my payload in json format as:

```
{
    "A":"true"
}
```

In this case B is not taking its assigned default value. Please suggest what can be possible reasons for that. As per https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/contribs/jersey-multipart/com/sun/jersey/multipart/FormDataParam.html, B should take assigned default value

Comment: Did you try to remove required attribute from the annotation?

Comment: @VoodooCoder the required attribute for that field is true, but it is taking null as the default value instead of the given one

Comment: I simply put  `protected String B ="xyz";` and it worked for me.